# Basic question with respect to Drupal form API

Tags: forms

I am learning the Drupal Form API. I am new to HTML and PHP also.
I read in a book how to define a form in Drupal, where they used the following example:

```
/**
* Define a form.
*/
function formexample_nameform() {
  $form['user_name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Your Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#description' => t('Please enter your name.'),
  );
}
```

What will the HTML equivalent of above example be?
Similarly, to validate the form they did it as follows:

```
/**
 * Validate the form.
 */
function formexample_nameform_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['user_name'] == 'King Kong') {
    // We notify the form API that this field has failed validation.
    form_set_error('user_name',t('King Kong is not allowed to use this form.'));
  }
}
```

What will be HTML equivalent of both of these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your question, you are reading a book that does not explain the relation between common html forms/behaviors facing same things in Drupal.

The html equivalent of your first function is a text field. An html example:

```
<label>User Name: </label>
<input type="text" value="" name="user_name">
```

see following guide for more information about text fields: http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmltextfields.php and other html form elements: http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/forms.php

And regarding your second function, (if I am not wrong) there is no equivalent in html4 for validations in a web page. a common ways is to use javascript (one example: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptform.php or server side languages/technics like php (one example: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-validation.html). with html you can build forms, not validate forms.

one note, if you are interested in Drupal and forms, an alternative is build forms using CCK module http://drupal.org/project/cck (without coding) for Drupal 6, or just use Drupal 7.

Also, if you are new in Drupal, HTML and PHP, alternatively you can start to learn Drupal without coding or touch APIs, HTML and PHP http://drupal.org/documentation/customization/tutorials/beginners-cookbook (Drupal 6), http://drupal.org/node/1062604 (Drupal 7)

Comment: moon.watcher thanks you understood it correctly.The book is Pro Drupal Development. www.apress.com/9781430228387

Answer (score 2):

The HTML produced from the first function (the form builder) can be roughly seen checking the code for the theme functions, which are at least two: [theme_textfield()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_textfield/7), and [theme_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_form/7). The exact output can change basing on the theme being used, and third-party modules installed on the site.

For the validation handler, the function that adds the class for form fields with a validation error is [_form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/_form_set_class/7), while the list of the validation error messages are set with [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/7), which uses the following snippet:

```
  if ($message) {
    drupal_set_message($message, 'error');
  }
```

The messages that are set with `drupal_set_message()` are then output with [theme_status_messages()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7).

Also in this case, the real output depends from the theme being used, and from other modules installed on the Drupal site; both can alter the output used for the rendering.